# Маршрутизация в express

Tags: node.js, express

Авторизация, проверяем сессию  и, если пользователя нет, рендерим соответствующий файл с формой авторизации
Выполнена маршрутизация след.образом:

```
module.exports=function(app){

app.get('/',function (req,res) {
    if (req.session.user) {
        res.render('user');
    }
    else {
        res.render('auth');
    }   
});

app.post('/logout',function(req,res){
    req.session.user=0;
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    req.session.user=req.body.username;
    res.redirect('/');
});

return app;
}
```

Осуществляется запрос через ajax
**Вопрос**: Лог-аут выполняется как надо, а вот при post '/login' сам запрос обрабатывает, но редиректа не происходит. С чем это связано?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

На самом деле всё было просто. Ajax перенаправляет данные, да и запрос в целом, на контроллер и ждет ответа. Контроллер может в теории перезагрузить страницу(но на правах обработчика запроса это произойдёт быстро), но всё равно вернётся на страницу, откуда был запрос. Решение есть, добавить в ajax функцию success такого вида

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    if(typeof data.redirect == 'string'){
        socket.close();
        window.location = data.redirect;
    }
}
```

Надеюсь была кому-то полезной